# Ruby on Rails tesseract-ocr gem path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, tesseract

I am using ruby on rails to run some OCR tasks.  I am attempting to use the tesseract-ocr gem (https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr).

In my Gemfile, if the tesseract-ocr gem is listed as below:
`gem 'tesseract-ocr'`

I get the following error:

`C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Rails\cx-master>rails c
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'tesseract-ocr'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: compile error: see logs at C:/Users/Redacted_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/.ffi-inline-0/6a21dd7f0d1fcf6ba9de29522e4ac8d7604046d7.log
Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/compilers/gcc.rb:35:incompile'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders/c.rb:114:in shared_object'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:90:inblock in build'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in instance_eval'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:inbuild'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:54:in singleton_inline'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:39:ininline'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/c.rb:34:in <module:C>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/c.rb:31:in'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/c.rb:29:in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:inrequire'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:inrequire'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:inrequire'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in block (2 levels) in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:ineach'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:ineach'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:108:inrequire'
C:/Users/Redacted/Desktop/Rails/cx-master/config/application.rb:7:in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:inrequire'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in require_application_and_environment!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:96:inperform'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:ininvoke_command'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in dispatch'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:inperform'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in'
bin/rails:4:in require'
bin/rails:4:in'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:ineach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:ineach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:108:inrequire'
        from C:/Users/Redacted/Desktop/Rails/cx-master/config/application.rb:7:in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:inrequire'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:96:inperform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:ininvoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:inperform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in'
        from bin/rails:4:in require'
        from bin/rails:4:in'`

(if I remove the gem, however, the app works just fine)

Tesseract is installed:
`C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Rails\cx-master>tesseract -v
tesseract 3.05.01
 leptonica-1.74.1
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.0) : libpng 1.6.20 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.3 : libopenjp2 2.1.0`

and so is the gem:
`C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Rails\cx-master>gem list tesseract-ocr
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
tesseract-ocr (0.1.8)`

PATHS are also set:
`Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`
`TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`

So the crux of the problem is: while the tesseract-ocr gem is listed in the Gemfile, I cannot run the app. I'm on day 3 of going round in circles with this error, so a fresh pair of eyes & any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Let me know the below solution work or not

Comment: Still searching for a solution here

Comment: Still searching

Comment: please share your rails,ruby version also uninstall the gem. And try reinstalling it

Answer (score -1):

For Windows you can install from this [link](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki)

First install these

```
 sudo apt-get install libtesseract-dev
```

And

```
sudo apt-get install libleptonica-dev
```

Then run this on your terminal

```
gem install 'tesseract-ocr'
```

Please install by this  [link](https://github.com/dannnylo/rtesseract). This **gem 'tesseract-ocr'** has been old and no support is provided.Try for the link which I have provided

Comment: Hi Aniket,
The problem I have is that the project is an existing project that uses tesseract-ocr. The other developer is active and still using the tesseract-ocr gem, though he uses Mac OS and not Windows like I do.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I am currently using Windows and hence those commands don't work for me. Do you know a work-around?

Comment: Hi Aniket, I have already downloaded tesseract from the "Tesseract at UB Mannheim" link on that page.  Tesseract is installed on my system, along with dependencies (see below):

Comment: Tesseract is installed:
C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Rails\cx-master>tesseract -v
tesseract 3.05.01
 leptonica-1.74.1
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.0) : libpng 1.6.20 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.3 : libopenjp2 2.1.0